# Stack Overflow question downloader in markdown or HTML format?

Tags: support, api, app-request, stackoverflow

I want to download [a series of questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=5&tab=relevance&q=%5Bvisual-c%2b%2b%5D%20is:question%20answers:1%20link%20error%20) from Stack Overflow; is there a tool or API that can do this? The download could be in markdown or HTML format. I basically want an offline reference for those.

Comment: Have a look if [this answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/218081/158100) helps...

Comment: Thanks rene, but also looking to download all answers of the questions. I basically want to access those error questions offline when travelling since I (try to) compile C++ projects during those times, and I need a KB of common cpp errors.